# Codeigniter posted double link in address bar when clicking href

Tags: php, codeigniter

help me with this code.

```
 <a href="<?php echo site_url('calculator/');?>"><< Kembali menghitung</a>
```

when i click the link it posted double like :
    http://localhost/belajarci/index.php/calculator/localhost/belajarci/index.php/calculator

ive tried to remove the href values but the page not refered to the home, its only change another value in my code.

Comment: did u checked the solution ?

Comment: You need to set `$config['base_url']` in /application/config/config.php to your CodeIgniter root - with a trailing slash. e.g. | http://example.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right it's redirecting on double url becasue of you need to include `$this->load->helper('url')` in your file / controller constructor or use *url helper* in **autoload.php**

Also do two things in your configuration:

1. Check the .htaccess file in project becasue may be you have set there any url redirect.
2. Check in config file for base url what you have set there.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this URL:

```
http://localhost/belajarci/index.php/calculator/localhost/belajarci/index.php/calculator
```

Because you need to include `$this->load->helper('url')` in your **file / controller constructor** or use `url` helper in autoload.php

After loading url helper your URL will work as you need.

*You can also follow the CI User Manual: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html*

Comment: @MochamadRamdannyLukman: if help accept the answer this will help to others by click on the left tick.